# Controlbar doesn't disable on safari ipad (video html5)

Tags: html, jwplayer

Controlbar doesn't disable on safari ipad (video html5)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>

<video height="270" width="480" id="myVideo" >
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>

<script type="text/javascript">

jwplayer("myVideo").setup({
controls:false,
'controlbar':'none',
modes: [
{ type: 'html5' },
{ type: 'flash', src: 'player.swf' }
]
});
</script>
```

everybody can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I believe for JW6 it has to be controls=false

Comment: thanks Ethan LongTail